# how to check whether object array is subset of other array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I need to check if arr1 is a subset of arr2, only if the ids of both elements are equal.

```
arr1 = [{id:1, value:8}, {id: 2, value: 9};
arr2 = [{id: 1, category: 'a1'}, {id: 2, category: 'a2'}, {id: 3, category: 'a3'}]
```

I could do it with plain JS. But i'm unable to do the same with Ramda. My ramda solution is resulting in error

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: g.call is not a function
```

Ramda solution

```
export const isSubset = (arr: Identifier[]) => all(
  compose(
    isNotNullOrEmpty,
    filter(propEq('id', identity), arr),
    prop('id')
  )
);
export const isNilOrEmpty = either(isNil, isEmpty);

export const isNotNullOrEmpty = compose(not, isNilOrEmpty);

isSubsetOfInputIdentifiers(arr2)(arr1))
```

Plain Js solution

```
arr1.every(
    (identifier) =>
      arr2?.findIndex(
        (identifier1) =>
          identifier1.id === identifier.id
      ) >= 0
  )
```

I need to implement it using ramda only. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Ramda doesn't supply any `isSubset` function, the necessary tools are there to write a simple version on your own:

```js
const isSubset = compose (isEmpty, differenceWith (eqProps ('id')))


const arr1 = [{id:1, value:8}, {id: 2, value: 9}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, category: 'a1'}, {id: 2, category: 'a2'}, {id: 3, category: 'a3'}]
const arr3 = [{id:1, value:8}, {id: 5, value: 11}];

console .log (isSubset (arr1, arr2))
console .log (isSubset (arr3, arr2))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {compose, isEmpty, differenceWith, eqProps} = R           </script>
```

Here, [`eqProps`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps) takes a property name and returns a predicate function which reports whether the two supplied parameters have the same value for that property.  [`differenceWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#differenceWith) takes a predicate function that reports if two values are equal and returns a binary function accepting two lists, and returning all the elements of the second parameter not in the first one according to that predicate.

We combine these, using [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose), with an obvious [`isEmpty`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isEmpty), and we get a reasonably compact `isSubset`.

Note that this is less efficient than a vanilla JS version such as

```js
const isSubset = (xs, ys) => 
  xs .every (x => ys .findIndex (y => x .id == y .id) > -1)
```

because we iterate over all the elements of the first set, even if we find an early one not included.

We could definitely write a Ramda version of that last with some of the same tools, if you're interested.  But I would only bother if the `isSubset` above demonstrates a real performance problem.

Comment: I experimented something with `lift(eqProps('id'))(arr1, arr2)` and then comparing the number of `true` with the length of `arr1` but wasn't happy with it. Do you see any use case for `lift` here? (Just wondering)

Comment: @customcommander: While I'd be curious to see what you've done, the only way I could see that working is if we can guarantee that both arrays have no duplicated ids.  If we have that, then we could definitely make something work, with `lift` over two arrays serving as a cross-product.  Even then, though, I think `xprod` might be more obvious.